# Regex: Matching exactly one occurrence

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches exactly one occurrence of a curly brace pair:

```
myString_{1-10}         -> match
myString_{hello}_xyz    -> match
myString_{1-10}_{hello} -> do not match
```

Here is my regex:

```
(\{)[^}]*(\})
```

The problem is that my regex also matches strings containing more than one occurrence of curly brace pairs... what am I missing?

Comment: How are unmatched braces handled?  For example, `myString_}{}` or `myString_{}_{`

Comment: Are you regex-ing a whole paragraph or going line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^[^{}]*\{[^}]*\}[^{}]*$
```

Explanation:

```
^[^{}]*    // Match 0 or more occurrences of character other than [{}]
 \{        // Match a `{`
 [^}]*     // Match 0 or more occurrences of character other than }
 \}        // Match a `}`
 [^{}]*$   // Match 0 or more occurrences of character other than [{}]
```

You need to take care of nested braces or unmatched braces too

Comment: And what if I only want the content between the curly braces? I've tried this ^[^{}]*(?<=\\{)[^}]*(?=\\})[^{}]*$ but it doesn't work

Comment: Just move the content within `{` and `}` in above regex to capture group. You are using look-arounds, that is why it failed. Use `^[^{}]*\{([^}]*)\}[^{}]*$`, and get the captured group `1`.

Comment: I need 2 distinct regex... one returning only the content between the curly braces (mystring{1-10} => 1-10) and another one returning the content and also the curly braces (mystring{1-10} => {1-10}. Do you see the point?

Comment: You can add another capture group then - `^[^{}]*(\{([^}]*)\})[^{}]*$`. Now `group 1` contains with curly braces. `group 2` contains content without curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

If you're regex-ing a whole variable containing all three lines, this is what you're looking for:

```
(\{.*?\})_*(?:\{)*
```

The output will include exactly what you're looking for.

This requires the "s" flag // dot matches all.

Comment: The underscore was just an example... Any character would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern in .net with the multiline mode:

```
(?<=^(?>[^{\n]*))\{[^}]*\}(?=[^{\n]*$)
```