# Single brace java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check for exactly one single brace using java regex.
I referred this - [Regex: Matching exactly one occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913146/regex-matching-exactly-one-occurrence), but not able to make sense out of it.

Pattern that I used :

```
(.+)(\\s*)[)]{1}(\\s*)$
```

**Test cases:**

XXXX )     - Matches

XXXX ))    - Matches (but should ideally fail)

The second case should fail as there are two braces instead of one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It matches both because first dot may match first brace. Use `.*[^)]` instead of `.+`. It means some char, maybe nothing, followed by a char that is not a brace.

Comment: Why using regex? `if(s.indexOf(')')==s.lastIndexOf(')'))` -> only one occurrence of `)`.

Comment: @halex nice one, though you should also test for -1

Comment: Can you describe your problem little more? What is the rule of accepting or rejecting strings? Does `)` always have to be at end of string? What if your string contains another `)`, lets say  `"(ab)cd(ef)"`? Adding more examples of correct and incorrect input would help use help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first eager matching `(.+)`. In the second case it matches `XXXX )` and then comes your `)` match. So replace your expression with:

```
([^)]+)(\\s*)[)]{1}(\\s*)$
```

and it works.

Comment: I had a typo in there: ([^)]+)(\\s*)[)]{1}(\\s*)$ is correct. But I am still not able to edit my answer.

Comment: Don't need to put {1} which is by default. Removing {1} will work fine.         ([^)]+)(\\s*)[)](\\s*)$

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
"^[^\\)]*\\)[^\\)]*$"
```

It also do not matches cases like:

```
xxxx ) xxxxx ) xxxxx
```