# RegEx: Match only = and not first char in ==

Tags: regex, delphi

I'm new to regex and I need an expression that matches on `=`, but not on `==`.
So for example:

```
[x] == [y] // No match
[x] = [y] // Match
```

All my self-made regular expressions get a match on the first `=` in `==`. I dont want that. I just want a match if the `=` is the only operator in the expression.

I'm working with delphi regular expressions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using TRegExpr or Delphi XE's regex?

Maybe this regex .+ = .+ is working out for you. See: https://regex101.com/r/AknyqF/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!=)=(?!=)
```

This will match equal sign if not preceded and followed by equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the whether the predecessor is not = and the successor is not false:

```
[^=]=[^=]
```

Have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/rhNSeu/1/) example. [Here](https://regexone.com/) is a little interactive tutorial wich covers the important cases.

Answer (score 0):

adapting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913146/regex-matching-exactly-one-occurrence) should do the trick:

```
(?:[^=]+(=)[^=]+)
```

Explanation:

```
(?:      // Do not capture group
[^=]+    // Match 1 or more occurrences of character other than [=]
(=)      // Match and capture a `=`
[^=]+    // Match 1 or more occurrences of character other than [=]
)        // End of group
```

Comment: Thanks! All given regular expressions select more than just the '='. For example: [x] == [y]. I want the match result to be '==' only. In your example it selects everything around the '=='.

Comment: See my updated answer. The capturing group is now a non capturing one and a capturing group has been added around the `=`.